# How to find the source of a rendered string?

Tags: translation, meta-value

I truly appreciate it if you could help me with this issue since I could not fix it for the last few days. I am currently using a journal publication plugin and when a new paper is submitted by the user or by the admin, the status of the paper is shown as "Under Review" or "Accepted". Although I have translated every single phrase into Turkish, on the page where users check their article status, "Under Review" phrase is still shown in English. There is no language file. I have digged through every single file and could not find that phrase. I thought it might be injected by the database, but I couldn't find anything on phpMyAdmin either. Probably, I do not know where to look exactly.

"Under Review" phrase or the actual status of the paper is called by this code:

```
case 'status':
    $status = get_post_meta($id, 'status', true);
    echo str_replace(' ', ' ', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $status)));
```

$status calls the phrase but I cannot find the "Under Review" phrase to translate into Turkish in any plugin file.

[image]

Thank you very much in advance.....

Comment: Hi, I've edited the title of your question to make it a bit more meaningful. It sounds like what you want to do is find where in Wordpress this string is so that you can change it, is that correct? If that's not right, please try to make the post title clearer and more specific to your problem.